# I want to use the foreign key model as forms in Django forms

Tags: python, django

I have two models in django farmer and tractor and i want to use both the models in single form on webpage so that with all the properties as there inputs like name, phone, email , id, price etc.

my models.py

```
class Farmer(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone =models.CharField(max_length=10)
    address = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    email_address = models.EmailField()

    def full_name(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name()


class Post(models.Model):
    tractor_price = models.IntegerField(max_length=150)
    implementation = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    purchase_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, db_index=True, null=True,blank=True)
    tractor_company = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    tractor_model = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(validators=[MinLengthValidator(10)])
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=False)
    farmer = models.ForeignKey(
        Farmer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name="posts")
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Post,Farmer

class PostForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ["tractor_price","implimentaion","purchase_date","tractor_company","tractor_model","description"]

class FarmerForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Farmer
        fields = ['first_name','last_name','phone','address','email_address']
```

views.py this is only the form function

```
def add_post(request):
    submitted = False
    if(request.method == "POST"):
        form1 = FarmerForm(request.POST,prefix="form1")
        form2 = PostForm(request.POST,prefix="form2")
        
        if form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
            form1.save()
            form2.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/add_post?submitted=True")
    else:
        form1 = FarmerForm(prefix="form1")
        form2 = PostForm(prefix="form2")
        if("submitted" in request.GET):
            submitted = True
    return render(request,"tractor/form.html",{"form1":form1,"form2":form2, "submitted": submitted})
```

here is my forms.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %} {% block content %}
<br />
<h1 style="margin-left: 40px">Add Event</h1>
<br />
{% if submitted %}
<h3 style="margin-left: 40px">Your Form is Submitted</h3>
{% else %}
<div class="form-group">
  <form method="POST" action="">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form1.as_p }}
{{ form2.as_p }}
<button type='submit'> send data </button>
</form>
</div>
{% endif %} {% endblock %}
```

I am able to submit the form but after submission I am not getting details of farmer like phone, email id etc in database. details of tractor are being saved after submitting but  detail of farmer is not bieng saved.